# Date/Time display issue

Tags: php, html, date, time

I would like to know about this coding:

```
<?php   
    echo "<p><h2>";
    echo date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");
    echo date('d-m-Y h:i:s a',time())."</h2></p>";  
?>
```

it does work and display date time properly, but my problem is, it display extra 1 at the starter of the date  `e.g 1mm/dd/yyyy , 108/12/2018` how do i remove the number 1 at the starter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try -

```
<?php   
    echo "<p><h2>";
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");
    echo date('d-m-Y h:i:s a',time())."</h2></p>";  
?>
```

OUTPUT-

> 12-08-2018 03:16:29 pm

Answer (score 4):

your are displaying `date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur")` before `echo date('d-m-Y h:i:s a',time())`. remove `echo` from `date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur")`.

`echo date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur")` displayed 1.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"); 
echo date('d-m-Y h:i:s a',time());
```

Output: `12-08-2018 03:16:08 pm`